# Ruby: One-Line If-Then-Else

Tags: ruby, syntax

I am wondering if there is a way in Ruby to write a one-line if-then-else statement using words as operators, in a manner similar to python's

```
a if b else c
```

I am aware of the classic ternary conditional, but I have the feeling Ruby is more of a "wordsey" language than a "symboley" language, so I am trying to better encapsulate the spirit of the language.

I also am aware of this method,

```
if a then b else c end
```

which is basically squishing a multi-liner onto one line, but the `end` at the end of the line feels cumbersome and redundant.  I think the ternary conditional would be preferable to this.

So for you who know Ruby well, is there a better way to write this? If not, which of the methods is the most Rubyesque?

---

**The following questions are not addressed by the linked post:**

1. Is there a cleaner way than `if a then b else c end` to write a "wordsey" one-line if-then-else in Ruby?
2. Is the ternary conditional or the wordsey version more appropriate for the Ruby paradigm?

Comment: @Apollys I haven't downvoted or voted to close since I'm not sure. If I did either, I would explicitly say so. The link was just a suggestion. Take it or leave it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Okay, coincidental timing then, my apologies kind sir.  I did read that topic before posting this.  (But notice that I wrote "I am aware of the classic ternary conditional...")

Comment: The duplicate *does* answer your question, including an answer that links to a style guide.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The two one liners that exist are the two you already described:

Ternary:

```
a ? b : c
```

if-struct:

```
if a then b else c end
```

So to answer your questions:

1. No.
2. The ternary is preferred according to  [this](https://shopify.github.io/ruby-style-guide/), [this](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide),
   while the if-struct is preferred according to [this](https://github.com/airbnb/ruby#ternary-operator), and [this](https://github.com/github/rubocop-github/blob/master/STYLEGUIDE.md). Ruby does not have an official style guide, you won't find a concrete answer I'm afraid. Personally, I use the if-struct, as it reduces cognitive load, if being more verbose.

However, all the most of the style guides say ternary operators are fine for simple constructs:

```
Avoid the ternary operator (?:) except in cases where all expressions are extremely trivial.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is very flexible and is often used to create Domain Specific Languages (DSLs), and while this example is not really a DSL, you could use it to create a more expressive ternary method on the object class.

```
def the_value(val, as_long_as:, otherwise:)
  as_long_as ? val : otherwise
end

some_thing = the_value 4, as_long_as: 1 > 0, otherwise: 5
=> 4
some_thing = the_value 4, as_long_as: 1 < 0, otherwise: 5
=> 5
```

You can change the method name, and parameters to fit whatever context you prefer.

ps: this assumes a ruby version >= 2.1